# Laravel: Add Where Clause To Appended Custom Attribute

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have added a custom attribute age (in months) like:

//Casted so that I can use Carbon instance

```
protected $dates = ['date_of_birth'];
```

//Returns age in month

```
public function getAgeAttribute(){
    if(empty($this->date_of_birth){
        return null;
    }
    return $this->date_of_birth->diffInMonths();
}
```

I then appended age so that I can globally use **age** like:

```
protected $appends = ['age'];
```

I now need to use the age month on generating report which displays based on the age month:

How can I filter based on **age** in the collection of users?

//General Setup

```
$ages = [10, 20, 30, ...];

$users = User::get();

$requiredDetail = [];
```

**Attempt 1**

I tried to use **where** clause but is not working

```
foreach($ages as $age){
    $requiredDetail[$age] = $users->where('age', $age)->count();
}
```

**Attempt 2**

I tried to use collection filter but is not working

```
foreach($ages as $age){
    $requiredDetail[$age] = $users->filter(function($user) use ($age){
        return $user->age == $age;
    });
}
```

The question is how can I filter casted age after retrieving it from the collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `WhereIn`

```
$requiredDetail = $users->whereIn('age', $age)->count();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Collection method `whereIn()`.

```
$usersCertainAge = $users->whereIn('age', $ages);
```